# passing data with callback

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, glib, pygobject

I'm creating an async child process with `gobject.spawn_async`, which generates data on stdout that I want to use when the child exits. So I create two callbacks (minimal example):

```
output = ""
def child_read(source, cb_condition):
    for line in source: output += line + "\n"

def child_done(pid, condition, user_data):
    print(user_data)

cpid, cout = gobject.spawn_async(['/bin/ls'],
                      flags = gobject.SPAWN_DO_NOT_REAP_CHILD,
                      standard_output=True)
gobject.child_watch_add(pid=cpid, function=child_done, data=output)
gobject.io_add_watch(os.fdopen(cout, 'r'), gobject.IO_IN | gobject.IO_PRI, child_read)
```

The obvious defect here is that `child_done` will always print nothing since `output` is reallocated in `child_read`. Now the question is, how do I do this in a syntactically nice and readable (i.e. self-documenting) way? Sure, I could just read `output` in `child_done`, but then the `child_watch_add` call doesn't document which data are used in the callback. Plus the callback can't be used for anything else. I'm really missing C/C++ pointer semantics here, since that would do just what I want.

I'm also aware that I could create a wapper class that emulates pointer semantics, but that kinda bloats syntax, too. So, any proposals for doing this "*pythonic*", i.e. **elegantly**, in a nice and readable way?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used gobject, but four hours is a long time for a Python question to remain unanswered on SO, so I'll give it a shot.

Make `output` a list of strings instead of a string.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
output = []

def child_read(source, cb_condition):
    output.extend(source)

def child_done(pid, condition, user_data):
    output_str = '\n'.join(user_data)
    print(output_str)
```

The rest of the code is unchanged (i.e. still use `data=output` in the call to `child_watch_add()`.

Comment: Yup, heard of that before, but it only fits because output is used to gather data. If output was just a single int, then wrapping it in a list would be bloat, too.

Comment: Yes, to implement the pattern that you are using here `output` must be mutable, and in Python, integers and strings are immutable.  (It's pretty clear you understand that; this comment is mainly for anyone else reading this later.)